# Wordpress multisite condition for certain blog_id's

Tags: multisite, themes

I have a function in my network's footer:

```
<?php 
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
if ( 446 == $blog_id ) {
?>
----my code-----
<?php } ?>
```

....How would this have to look if I want

1.) all blog IDs 446 and above to be included?

and

2.) only a certain part of the blog title to be included? (Let's say I only want this code to appear when the blog title contains the word 'test')?

Is that even possible?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is easy. The following condition is for all sites with ID equal or higher than 446 that at the same time have a blog title that contains the four letters **test** next to each other, whether they have intervals around them or not (so keep in mind it will include other words too, like **testify** or **protest** unless we change the code a little).

```
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
$blog_details = get_blog_details( $blog_id );
if ( strpos( $blog_details->blogname, 'test' ) !== false && $blog_id >= 446 ) {
    // Run some code here
}
```

Comment: Pretty cool!! Works like a charm, thanks a LOT!! :)

Comment: @user141856 Thanks, I am glad you like it. Consider accepting my answer as the solution, so other people know this question is solved. Regards.